# OpenGL Texture Projection Go Through Surface

Tags: python, opengl, textures, projection

I'm new here and I'm also new to openGL. I want to develop some kind of viewer which load .ply files, images as texture, and project it to the mesh. I want to ask about the texture projection. The code of loading texture and set the projection of the texture can be seen bellow:

```
def loadTexture():
   # load the image
   imdata = 0
   imname = 'Cropped_Image26904_2.jpg'
   texture = glGenTextures(1)
   im = cv2.imread(imname)
   imdata = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
   # bind texture
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture)
   glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, imdata.shape[1],
   imdata.shape[0], 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imdata)
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, 
   GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER)
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, 
   GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER)
   glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, 
   GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER)
   glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, 
   GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER)
   gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGB, imdata.shape[1], 
   imdata.shape[0], GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imdata)
   # set the 'projector' location that project the texture
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
   glPushMatrix()
   glLoadIdentity()
   gluPerspective(fov, 
   float(glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH))/glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT), .1, 
   1e8)
   gluLookAt(0,0,1, 0,0,0, 0,1,0)
   mat3 = glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX)
   # mapping the texture
   glTexGeni(GL_S, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_EYE_LINEAR)
   glTexGenfv(GL_S, GL_EYE_PLANE, mat3[0])
   glTexGeni(GL_T, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_EYE_LINEAR)
   glTexGenfv(GL_T, GL_EYE_PLANE, mat3[1])
   glTexGeni(GL_R, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_EYE_LINEAR)
   glTexGenfv(GL_R, GL_EYE_PLANE, mat3[2])
   glTexGeni(GL_Q, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_EYE_LINEAR)
   glTexGenfv(GL_Q, GL_EYE_PLANE, mat3[3])
   # enable the texture
   glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
   glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S)
   glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T)
   glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_R)
   glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_Q)
```

This one works fine to some extend. Here are a screenshots of it:
[The viewer form front. The pink ball is the 'projector' position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tnlwi.png)

The problem is that the projected texture went through the box and also leave a projection on the back side of the box:
[The texture also projected to the backside of the cube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phY73.png)

So, the question is, how to make the projection of the texture only appears on the face that visible to the 'projector'? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, the question is, how to make the projection of the texture only appears on the face that visible to the 'projector'? Thank you very much.

Disable the texture when drawing the *backside* of the box.

Or do you expect a shadow to appear on the box? OpenGL is not a global illumination renderer that operates on whole scene. In fact OpenGL is just a glorified pencil that draws single points, lines or triangles, one at a time, without any interaction between each of them, except for the effects they have on the values of the pixels in the framebuffer.

Comment: Hey datenwolf, thank you for your answer. I tried the solution to disabled texture before drawing the cube by `glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` but the resulting render is like this: http://imgur.com/kYjoz9K 
Is there anything that I'm missing?

Comment: @ResindraAji: Sorry, I had a few words missing in the answer: You have of course to disable the texture only when drawing the backside of the box. *Or you could move away from the fixed function pipeline and use shaders instead, where it's actually possible to decide if to apply the texture depending on outside criteria, like, is a face actually pointing toward the projector.* Shaders make *everything* easier, so you should really use them.

Comment: ahh I see. And I actually tried your solution and it did works. Thank you very much. For this cube application, turning on and off the texture is doable because it only has 6 face. So I think for my application which could include thousands of faces, I should learn to use shaders. Thank you very much.